# Set/Scale image size in android app

Tags: android

So In my code i take an image file location from an array called filelocationarray. Then i use .setImageBitmap to set the ImageView to the image file. What i want to do is set the size of the ImageView as it displays on the screen. In java i used this code:

```
img.getScaledInstance(75, 75,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

But i haven't been able to figure out a similar way in android. Bellow is my code that i use so far to display the image. Can anyone give me som ehelp?

```
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filelocationarray.get(0));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

EDIT:

I tried using this code but it doesn't work:

```
        Bitmap bMap;
        bMap.createScaledBitmap (accstringarray.get(acc1int), 75, 75, true);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method [`#createScaledBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) of `android.graphics.Bitmap`.

Comment: It messes with the size of the image - makes it look distorted